# Any way to speed up initialization of statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression.KernelReg

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a kernel regression to data (n is approx 230,000). I am using `statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression.KernelReg`, which works nicely on small amounts of data but is taking multiple hours to initialize on even a small subset of my table. Has anyone experienced this before? Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to get results fast with the current statsmodels implementation, that one is implemented with python loops which are to slow for large datasets.

Comment: Alternatives, use spline regression instead, or predict values only on a grid of values instead of evaluating at the full sample.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, it seemed like specifying a default value for the bandwidth dramatically increased the speed. Obviously might not work in every context but in mine we have a good sense of what we want the bandwidth to be.